# Cannot install macOS update with error "cannot verify this update"

Tags: macos, software-update

While installing the macOS 10.12.6 Sierra update from the Mac App Store, my system rebooted with the error, “Cannot verify this update.”

I’m trying to upgrade from macOS 10.12.5 to 10.12.6.

Comment: Hi Quanlong, it may be helpful if you include the version of macOS you currently have installed and the version you're trying to update to. Also, it may be good to include the exact model of Mac you're trying to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the [macOS Sierra 10.12.6 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1931/en_US/macosupdcombo10.12.6.dmg) instead. Then open the `dmg` file and run the installer.

The combo updater includes all minor updates since the `.1` release, and it is therefore larger than the delta update. However since it reapplies any system changes brought on by previous updates, it should resolve any issues that came up during regular updates.